# DataStax - OpsCenter LifeCycle Manager (Failed to Start LSB: DataStax Enterprise)

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am currently trying to create a cluster using LCM and one my nodes fails with the error `Failed to Start LSB: DataStax`. I have attempted to edit certain files to solve the issue but to no avail.

I setup OpsCenter via Tarball and configured a cassandra DC along with graph and search in LCM. When I run install for the cluster the job fails at the "/usr/bin/systemctl restart dse" command with the error "Failed to start LSB:DataStax Enterprise is encountered". Any advise on fixing this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's in your system.log and output.log in the node? There can be found by default in `/var/log/cassandra`

Comment: @phact, thank you for your advice I have found the issue and fixed it. It was an issue with the broadcast_native_transport_address defaulted to my native_transport_address which was 0.0.0.0 (wildcard address). I solve this by changing the value to my node's actual IP address. It seems to work but is that the correct way to solve this?